# Qt is not linking to sql

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I've been searching for similar problem but none is specific to mine..

It looks like the Qt is not linking to sql even though I add QT += sql on the .pro file(which does enable me to have auto fill when I try to include qtsql).

this is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Mysql_Testing
TEMPLATE = app


DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui



//
```

I'm on OS X 10.12 with qt version 5.9.1.

EDIT:
After deleting

```
 HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h
```

In the .pro file it solves my problem.  It seems I delete the original .h file without delete the definition in the .pro file as well

Comment: 1. Don't add code and output as images, [edit] it *into the queston* as text. 2. `MainWindow` doesn't appear to be a Qt class, so it's likely an issue with your code and not with Qt.

Comment: Thanks you, I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the platform.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have declared the destructor `MainWindow::~MainWindow()` in the header file, but have not supplied a definition anywhere (e.g. in the CPP file).

Comment: Thank you!! It solved my problem.  I'm being stupid for sure!